# What happens to a binary star system when one of the stars explodes and loses a lot of mass

Tags: astrophysics, planetary-science

If one star of a binary system explodes and leaves a remnant. The remnant would still have the velocity but lack the mass of the original star.

Comment: Are you asking what happens to the stars' orbits?

Comment: If it explodes. Sudden loss of mass. Would it still retain its velocity and so leave the system.

Comment: Why would losing momentum and kinetic energy make it leave the system?

Comment: If two stars of equal mass are orbiting a single point and one loses half its mass it must have some effect on their relative orbits

Comment: Hi Michael. Exploding stars don't leave a white dwarf. They leave a neutron star, a black hole, or nothing. Are you're interested in 1) the fate of a white dwarf in a binary, or 2) the fate of a binary where one component explodes? I think #2, but you should probably clarify in your question.

Comment: I am asking what happens to the binary star system when one of the stars loses a large amount of its mass. I don't think I can put it much clearer. not really interested if the remnant is a red or white dwarf or a neutron star.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the stars explodes and a lot of mass leaves the system, then the system will rearrange itself into a new equilibrium with a lower binding energy or, if the new binding energy is negative, the system will become unbound altogether.

Exactly what will happen will depend exactly on (i) how much mass the system had to begin with; (ii) how much mass is lost from the system during the explosion; (iii) whether some fraction of that mass is accreted by the companion; (iv) what the orbital separation and eccentricity was to begin with; (vi) how quicky the mass is lost (although the implication of the question is that it is "instantaneous" compared with the orbital period of the binary).

Answer (score -2):

Nice question. It's orbit would most certainly be effected, but it depends upon the mass of the SNR (Super nova remanant), which in turn depends upon the mass of the main star in the binary system. So if it explodes either into a neutron star or black hole, according to the no hair hair theoerem, it will retain the mass of the star, which will be above the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff limit for black hole, and chandrashekhar limit for neutron stars, so if the star exploded in the sense, then most likely it's orbit would not be affected. **However**, if it swelled into a red giant, and shedded it's outer layer, leaving it's iron core behind known as a white dwarf, then the most likely scenario is, the star will wander into the depth of outer space, carrying the white dwarf along with it, as it's moon, but if the semi-major axis between the 2 stars was distant, most probably the gravitational attraction would not be sufficient to attract it and make it orbit. In, the earlier binary system arrangement, the barycenter was more distributed than it is now cause it lost small of the mass, in case  the white dwarf star and the bigger star get separated then they both will wander off into their own trajectories, but if the radius was close enough, perhaps it could have gravitationall attracted it and put it in a stable orbit because according to the inverse square law, the force field strength is inversely proportional to distance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another additional question. In a case where the white dwarf had wandered off as you say. Would there be anyway to tell by looking at the remaining star that it had once had a companion star.